# time limited in SPOJ(i.e. 2. Prime Generator) with scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to solve the problem (prime generator) in SPOJ with scala. But it remind me that "time limited". Anyone knows that's why?

The following is my code.

```
var testCaseNumber = readInt()

for (index <- 1 to testCaseNumber) {
  val range: Array[String] = readLine().split(" ")

  (math.max(range(0).toInt, 2) to range(1).toInt).filter(num => {
    var flag = true
    for (element <- 2 to math.sqrt(num).toInt) {
      if (num % element == 0) {
        flag = false
      }
    }
    flag
  }).foreach(println)

  println("")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but not scala related. Your algorithm is just too slow.

Segmented sieve of eratosthenes is your friend.

https://turjachaudhuri.wordpress.com/2013/12/14/spoj-prime-1-segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes/